Why do I get "Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code"? (LinkedIn API error)
I am having issue with getting LinkedIn access token.
I was able to get authorization code using npm package 'react-linkedin-login-oauth2' but when I use the returned code the API 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken' gives 400 error code.

Used the code with Postman as soon as authorization code is created.
I can't find any solutions to this issue.

According to the official LinkedIn documentation, redirect_uri must match exactly one of the configured URIs in your LinkedIn application settings. Make sure it matches.
If it does, try to use a URL from a real domain (e.g., not http://localhost).
And Instead of using the npm package, I'd recommend following LinkedIn's official Postman tutorial for testing the OAuth flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/postman-getting-started
